# Can We Connect DB with Lambda in dotnet 6.0?

Tags: .net, database, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I set up a local server in my system and a Lambda function that refers to it. I currently hosted that function on AWS, but it is displaying an error message that says:

> LocalDB is not supported on this Platform

Does anyone have idea how to resolve this error ?

Comment: Which OS are you using?

Comment: Using Windows..

Answer (score 0):

To answer the question in the title, "Can We Connect DB with Lambda in dotnet 6.0?", yes that is possible; however, it seems you are trying to access SQL Server Express' LocalDB from a Lambda function. The later part is not possible on Lambda. This is because AWS manages the EC2 instances Lambda runs on, and you cannot create a LocalDB on that instance. You will need to connect to an external DB from your Lambda function.

If you would like to setup a MSSQL Server on Amazon RDS and connect it to your Lambda function, [this blog post](https://nodogmablog.bryanhogan.net/2022/04/accessing-an-rds-sql-server-from-a-net-6-application-in-lambda/) talks through doing that.